# Kerberos authorization to add another user

Tags: active-directory, ansible, kerberos, ansible-2.x, klist

I am doing Ansible setup on Linux to connect Windows (host) machine, I have  successfully connected using [KERBEROS method](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#active-directory-support).

I have added user using the following command:

```
kinit -C user_1@EXAMPLE.COM
```

and I can check the details using klist, it showed the details tickets.

but I want to add another user i.e user_2 , when I am trying to run the `kinit -C user_2@EXAMPLE.COM`, it overrides the existing klist, I want see both tickets (user_1 & user_2)

my object is using ansible I want to run the playbook on different-different user ( user_1 , user_2)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *add* an extra user to an *existing* ticket cache; but you can create *distinct* caches for distinct users, and switch context.

```
# new context, new ticket for other account
export KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u)_biloute
kinit biloute@EXAMPLE.COM
...
# switch back to default context
unset KRB5CCNAME
...
# switch again
export KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u)_biloute
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch user(su) between user_1 and user_2 using Kerberized version of 'ksu' and try klist after that.

In otherwords, use the Kerberos programs ksu in place of its non-Kerberos counterparts su. Then try klist

Thanks

Kumar